# EasyUI: grid using 'fitColumns:true' will show the white area

Tags: jquery-easyui

[image: the grid-in easyUI]

and even in the offical-demo:

[image]

So how can I remove this region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just set the data-option  scrollbarSize:0